# Save Changes Error cannot call abstract class c#

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

This code worked fine in ef 4.0 but I have just upgraded to ef 5.0 and got the following error on calling save changes

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Objects;
using OSPos.DBContext;

namespace OSPos.OSPosContext
{
    public abstract class ContextBase
    {
        public abstract bool SaveChanges();

        protected bool SaveChanges(ObjectContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                int i = context.SaveChanges();
                if (i == 0)
                    return false;

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new EntityContextException("SaveChanges failed.", ex);
            }

        }

        public abstract void DeleteObject(object entity);

        protected void DeleteObject(ObjectContext context, object entity)
        {
            try
            {
                context.DeleteObject(entity);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new EntityContextException("DeleteObject failed.", ex);
            }
        }

        protected static string pamsConnectionString;

        public static string PamsConnectionString
        {
            set { pamsConnectionString = value; }
        }

        protected static string pamssysdbfConnectionString;

        public static string PamssysdbfConnectionString
        {
            set { pamssysdbfConnectionString = value; }
        }

        #region Encryption Fields

        public static string encryptionServiceUrl;
        public static bool encryptionEnabled = false;
        private static string encryptionTicket;

        #endregion
    }
}
```

My calling class is as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using CMSNIDataobjects.Lookups;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;
using OSPos.OSPosContext;

namespace OSPos.OSPosContext
{
    public class cmsContext : ContextBase
    {
        private  OSPosEntities1  _OsPosEntities;
        protected OSPosEntities1 OSPosEntities
        {
             get
             {
                 if (_OsPosEntities == null)
                 {
                 // try
                 // {
                        _OsPosEntities = new OSPosEntities1();//knowledgebaseEntities1(@"metadata=res://*/KnowledgeBase.csdl|res://*/KnowledgeBase.ssdl|res://*/KnowledgeBase.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DAVID_BUCKLEY\DBSQLSERVER28R2;initial catalog=knowledgebase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;");}
                 //}
                 //catch (Exception ex)
                 //{
                 //    throw new EntityContextException("cmsEntities object could not be created.", ex);
                 //}
                }
                return _OsPosEntities;
            }
        }

        public override int  SaveChanges()
        {
            return base.SaveChanges();
            //this is where i am getting the error in reference to abstract class
        }

        public override void DeleteObject(object entity)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what exception does it throw?

Comment: You cannot call this method because it's abstract. What is your question?

Comment: PS. Your inheritor `cmsContext` of abstract `ContextBase` class doesn't override abstract methods bool SaveChanges(). So it won't compile

Comment: The upgrade from a previous version is clearly not the error here. This doesn't compile and never did.

Answer (score 0):

The class `ContextBase` is abstract and must be overridden.  You've done that.  But the method `SaveChanges()` is also abstract, and too must be overridden.

If `ContextBase` is your invention, then perhaps these changes would help.

If you want to *require* overriding, then leave the line:

`public abstract bool SaveChanges();`

... and remove the base method altogether.  Then simply provide the override in `cmsContext`.  Otherwise, remove it and change the base method to `virtual`:

```
protected virtual bool SaveChanges(ObjectContext context)
{
    try
    {
        int i = context.SaveChanges();
        if (i == 0)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new EntityContextException("SaveChanges failed.", ex);
    }
}
```

Do the same for the other method you obviously want to use, `DeleteObject`.

Making these `virtual` will allow you the flexibility to override only when you need specific functionality in the derived class that differs from the base class.  Otherwise, you simply use the `base.SaveChanges()` call you originally attempted and you get what is in `BaseContext`.